# Touchstart click event is not working for iPhone / iPade

Tags: jquery, iphone, click, window.open, touchstart

I've written an event to open new browser tab (`window.open`) by jQuery like below:

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '.myClass', {self: this}, function (e) {

    var mylink = e.data.self.validateDomValue(this, 'attr=data-affiliate')

    if(myLink)
    {
        window.open(mylink, '_blank');
    }
});
```

This scripts working well for windows, mac and iPad but the problem is arising for iPhone. The event is not firing for iPhone (version: 5, 6 and 7). What was my mistake? Any of your suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! Yes! I got the point. I need to use css `cursor:pointer`. That works for me.

```
if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) 
{
    $(".myClass").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css cursor:pointer didn't work for me once the element I used was on 'position:fixed'.
I added a 'click' event listener and it solved the case.
Once I click on the element only one of the events is fired.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a few more details. In what versions of iOS/Safari did the trick the previous answer not work?